# Restore spinner position in Fragment, after screen rotation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, spinner, screen-rotation

As I wrote in title the title, I want restore selected position in spinner, after screen rotation. Tried do this by saving position in bundle, and get position from `savedInstanceState` after rotation in

```
onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { }
```

or

```
onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

or

```
onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

but no one works :-/

## AddRecipeFragment

```java
public class AddRecipeFragment extends Fragment implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks {


    private static final String SELECTED_CATEGORY = "SELECTED_CATEGORY";
    private Spinner categoriesSpinner;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_recipe, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        categoriesSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.categories_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.categories, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        categoriesSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            categoriesSpinner.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_CATEGORY, 0), true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(SELECTED_CATEGORY, categoriesSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    }
}
```

I have also tried `setSelection(position, false)` with **false**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all that failed, why don't you use a static variable?!

```
private static int selectedPosition = 0;
```

and when spinner item selected

```
categoriesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectedPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

and inside `onViewCreated()` method

```
categoriesSpinner.setSelection(selectedPosition);
```